# JSON data with array structure

Tags: json, web-services, http

I am using Neo4j and ExtJS in my application.

One good thing is that both handle JSON with array structure.

Neo4j returns and ExtJS can consume JSON like this:

```
{
  columns: ["name", "age"],
  data: [
    ["Peter", 34],
    ["Mike", 52]
  ]
}
```

instead of:

```
[
  {"name": "Peter", "age" 34},
  {"name": "Mike", "age" 52},
]
```

However, from my application server's HTTP API I want people to be able to choose which one of these JSON structures to receive.

So they are both JSON which means the HTTP header should be "Accept": "application/json". But how should I allow them to pick either one of the structures? Should they set a header or a query param?  What is best practice?

Comment: It's best if you use query parameter, since they are both JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a simple param in the request would be enough.